# How to write a where on column base another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with two columns: `col1` and `col2`.

I want to create select that return all the rows except where I have `col1 != foobar` AND `col2` is `bar_id` or `foo_id`.

But no matter what I did it not work:

```
select * from table1 where col1 != 'foobar' and (col2 = 'bar_id' or col2 = 'foo_id')

select * from table1 where (col2 = 'bar_id' or col2 = 'foo_id') and col1 = 'foobar'

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE NOT col1 = 'foobar' AND (col2 = 'bar_id' OR col2 = 'foo_id');
```

So how should I write the correct sql select? I want to remove `('foobar', 'foo_id'), ('foobar', 'bar_id')` from the results.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/50982/3)

the expect result:

[image]
**sql**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([col1] varchar(6), [col2] varchar(11))
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    ([col1], [col2])
VALUES
    ('bar', 'text'),
    ('foo', 'foo_id'),
    ('foo', 'description'),
    ('foobar', 'foo_id'),
    ('foobar', 'bar_id'),
    ('foobar', 'update')
;
```

Comment: try to do it without round brackets, tell me if it works for you

Comment: no. it still don't return the results I expect

Comment: can you share your expected result ?

Comment: yes. check my question.it should remove `foobar: foo_id` and `foobar: bar_id`. and keep the rest

Comment: why you expect the last one result? foobar-update ? you don't say that you don't whant foobar?

Comment: or you don't whant foobar - barid and foobar - foo-id togheter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table1 where NOT (col1 = 'foobar' and (col2 = 'bar_id' or col2 = 'foo_id'))
```

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE NOT col1 = 'foobar' AND (col2 = 'bar_id' OR col2 = 'foo_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using EXCEPT in SQL

```
select col1,col2 from table1 except select col1,col2 from table1 where col1 ='foobar' and col2 in ('bar_id','foo_id');
```

Not a very clean and optimized solution, but can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create select that return all the rows except where I have col1 != foobar AND col2 is bar_id or foo_id.

This logic as expressed would be:

```
WHERE NOT (col1 <> 'foobar' AND col2 IN ('bar_id', 'foo_id') );
```

This can be simplified to:

```
WHERE col1 = 'foobar' OR col2 NOT IN ('bar_id', 'foo_id') );
```

This is not equivalent to the answer you accepted, so I'm wondering my interpretation of your logic is correct.  However, this is specifically what your question is asking for.